# Any open source server based on ACE framework?

Tags: c++, frameworks, network-programming, ace

anyone aware on open source project that uses [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) as the framework?

Thanks,

I.

Answer (score 2):

TAO (The ACE ORB), an open-source implementation of a CORBA Object Request Broker.

Comment: Well, TAO is practicably part of the ACE framework; so that not what I was aiming for. 

Thnaks,
I.

Answer (score 2):

[Trinity core](http://www.trinitycore.info) open source MMORPG server [uses ACE](http://code.google.com/p/trinitycore/source/browse/#hg/externals/ace)

Might be worth asking on the [mailing list](http://list.isis.vanderbilt.edu/mailman/listinfo/ace-announce) - there is some activity on there.

Answer (score 1):

the [Who uses ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-users.html) page lists an open source project called [osmius](http://www.osmius.com/) ([SVN repo](https://osmius.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/osmius)).

Comment: Thanks, but that's the only mentioned there. The things is that for such a framework I would expect more OS project using it.
and it makes me wonder why i can't fins any.

I.

Comment: well, many OS projects are written on/for Unix using C, so using ACE is out of question for those projects. Additionally i many OS projects have their own Operating System Abstraction layer e.g. Mozillas NSPR, maybe written before ACE became popular...

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE-users.html for a big list of projects using ACE